# Julia copying folder into an existing folder

Tags: julia

Hi I am wondering how to copy folders into an existing folder in julia. In my case I have a folder called BigEarthNet-v1.0 which contains a number of sub-folders where each subfolder contains a number of tif files (i.e BigEarthNet-V1.0 -> [folder1, folder2, ...], where folder1 -> [image1.tif,image2.tif, ...]). I want to copy randomly 100 subfolders into an exiting folder called BigEarthNet-v1-concise. Literally make a concise dataset.

```
folders = readdir("BigEarthNet-v1.0")
random_paths = rand(folders, 100)
for folder in random_paths
    cp(joinpath("BigEarthNet-v1.0",folder), "BigEarthNet-v1.0-concise", force = true)
end
```

If I don't enter `force = true` i get an error. If I do the code works but literally only the last folder gets copied and it is also the files inside the folder rather than the folder itself. From what I am understand `force =true` deletes the existing folder `BigEarthNet-v1-concise` and recreates the folder again and this is why I get this behavior. Anyway to achieve what I am trying to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
from = "BigEarthNet-v1.0"
to = "BigEarthNet-v1.0-concise"
mkdir(to)
folders = readdir(from)
random_paths = rand(folders, 100)
for folder in random_paths
    cp(joinpath(from, folder), joinpath(to, folder))
end
```

[The POSIX `cp` command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cp.html) behaves differently depending on if the target is an existing directory or not. This can make commands less verbose. If `dir` is an existing directory: `cp "$path" dir` is equivalent to `cp "$path" "dir/$(basename "$path")"`

> If target exists and names an existing directory, the name of the corresponding destination path for each file in the file hierarchy shall be the concatenation of target, a single `<slash>` character if target did not end in a `<slash>`, and the pathname of the file relative to the directory containing source_file.

This makes common usage in the shell less verbose but it is less explicit and a decision has been made not to replicate this behavior in Julia. See e.g. [this issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/36675).